# How to remove whitespace from within a string using zod

Tags: zod

I have a form in my project which contains a phone number. I would like to check the number is written the French way i.e `xx xx xx xx xx` (five pairs of digits, each pair separated by a space).

For this I could write a regex and use it as I have done for other fields, but I would like to be more lenient with the input so that I end up with 10 digits even if the user adds spaces in their response. I will rectify and additional whitespaces in the string using `transform`.

I tried

```js
z.string().trim().transform((val,ctx)=>{
  if(val.length!==10){
    ctx.addIssue({
      code: z.ZodIssueCode.custom,
      message: "You must enter 10 digits",
    })
    return z.NEVER;
  }
  var parts=val.match(/.{1,2}/g)
  return parts.join(' ')
})
```

Also the `trim()` alone did not work:

```js
z.string().trim()
```

does not return what I expected.

Comment: I just made a somewhat major edit to this post in an effort to make it more suitable for SO (based on the community guidelines) but I don't want to totally steamroll your intent. I think this may boil down to being simply a debugging issue where `trim`'s use case was misunderstood, but I also think there's more to the original question about how to format things into the specific shape from French phone numbers. That full parsing was not present in the original code (ie checking for numbers only) and there may be more and varied suggestions to help you more with your specific use case.

Comment: I think the question of how do I validate french phone numbers would have been another direction to take your question in, but I felt like the core of your original question was about how to remove whitespace from the middle of a string with `zod` which is something that could be useful to others in the future!

Comment: Perhaps you could ask another question more generally about parsing french phone numbers to see some alternative approaches that avoid the need to remove whitespace at all. I think `<input type="tel">` with a `pattern` attribute might be even more appropriate here to let the browser enforce some constraints before things even get to `zod` in the first place (for example).

Answer (score 0):

`trim` will only remove leading and trailing whitespace (and will not touch whitespace within a string). You can verify this for yourself by checking the output of the following:

```js
import { z } from "zod";
console.log(z.string().trim().parse("  hi there   ")); // Logs "hi there"
```

Note that the `' '` character in the center of the string remains. To remove all whitespace from a string in your transform step, you can use [`String.prototype.replaceAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll)

```js
const schema = z.string()
.trim()
.transform((s, ctx) => {
  const withoutWhitespace = s.replaceAll(/\s*/g, '');
    if (withoutWhitespace.length !== 10) {
      ctx.addIssue({
      code: z.ZodIssueCode.custom,
      message: "You must enter 10 digits",
    })
    return z.NEVER;
  }
  return withoutWhitespace;
});
console.log(schema.safeParse("12345678910")); // Logs a failure result
// The following parses successfully and strips out the whitespace.
console.log(schema.parse(" 0 1 2 3 4 5 6\n\r\t 7 8 9 "));
```

The `replaceAll` method has pretty broad browser support although it is still somewhat new. You may want to consult [Can I Use This](https://caniuse.com/?search=replaceAll) for your specific use case. (It should be possible to polyfill in the event you need to support older browsers, like IE11). You may also need to update your `lib` option in your `tsconfig` to include support for it.

Comment: Thank you for your help.In fact phone number adaptation is just a pretext. I took this example only to expose my problem that is the fact that nothing happens in the submitted values when I use the transform function. I know that trim() removes only leading and trailing white spaces and that is not my point. My point is that whatever I do in the transform, nothing happens to the submitted data. Probably I miss something basic in the way of using zod. Looking at your example it seems to me that I should add  something in my onSubmit function.

Comment: As for the " ",it is something I did on purpose to have my final string like xx xx xx xx xx whatever it was at first for example. to convert  xxx x xxxx xx into xx xx xx xx xx and have my onSubmit function transmitting the transformed data. To take the example of trim() that doesn't work as I expect, entering 3 white  spaces then 77 7777 77 then 2 white spaces what I get in the console is the original input i.e. the console output has still the 3 leading spaces and the 2 trailing spaces. My point is only this. But what I am missing ??

Comment: I also agree with you on the fact that I should also find a way of removing internal white spaces before inserting new ones after each pair of digits and checking for number but in reality my true concern is why doing some stuff in the transform function has no effect on the output of the onSubmit function?

Comment: As I am new to both nuxt and zod, I didn't understood that the schema.parse function should be used in the onSubmit function to get the validated and transformed data. It seems that it was the answer to my probably clumsily exposed question. Thank you for having helped me getting this point.